# Go to line in Atom editor from command line

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, terminal, atom-editor

Most editors allow you to pass an argument when opening a file from the command line to go to a specific line number (and column) in the file.

How can I do this with Atom?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Atom can open files and go to a specific line/column from the command line by appending `:line_number` or `:line_number:column_number` to the file name/path.

Examples:

```
atom README.md:58
atom README.md:57:5
atom myproject/Makefile:5:2
```

If the file is already open, it will move the cursor to the desired position.

If the column is omitted, it goes to the first column. If the line/column is greater than the number of lines in the file or columns in the line, it goes to the last line/column.

Comment: This is the most detailed yet simple and to the point answer.

Answer (score 22):

Atom commands are similar to Visual Studio and sublime text in this scenario. First press the  **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>** in your keyboard then you will redirect to command line in the Atom editor, then type line number to navigate that line Number.

[image: Command Line for Atom]

Comment: i think you can open using  command as         atom filename.txt , but you cannot navigate to certain line using commandline

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it is still useful to know

Comment: @Pavan that is not true, see other answers

Answer (score 14):

The proper format for doing this is the following:

filename.txt:linenumber

example:

```
atom /your/path/to/the/file.txt:208
```